# My model in Netlogo didn't stop in my condition

Tags: netlogo

I'm doing my project at my university and I coded the simple and more complex spreading disease model. My condition is if no more sick people from the disease so the model will stop immediately. In the simple one, I have code like this below.

```
if not any? turtles with [health-state = "I"] [stop]
```

The simple one is work and after I used this code to the more complex model one and it doesn't work. After that, I changed to another code that would not work too and the model didn't stop.

```
if not any? children with [health-state = "I"] and not any? adults with [health-state = "I"] and not any? elderly with [health-state = "I"] [stop]
```

So I would like to know how could I fix my code? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong with your code. After you think it should have stopped, stop it manually and then enter `inspect one-of turtles with [health-state = "I"]` in the command center. That will either give you an error to tell you there aren't any, or it will open an inspect window for a turtle that you think should not be in "I" state but still is.

Comment: I followed you already and I got INSPECT expected input to be agent but got NOBODY instead.

Comment: okay, that's good since it means there aren't any turtles with health-state of "I". What procedure is this line of code inside? Is it in the go procedure or not? `stop` will end the procedure but that only ends the model if the procedure being stopped is the main loop.

Comment: That procedure is in the go procedure. As I mentioned before, in simple model, my model was stop but in complex one did’t stop. Now I’m very curious what going on then :((

Comment: try brackets so `if (not any? ...) and (not any? ...)...` I wouldn't have thought that would fix it as `with` is highest precedence and `and` is lowest, but it's worth a try and makes the code more readable at the same time.

Comment: As JenB noted above,  the "stop" command is not a "halt" command -- it only breaks you out of the current loop you are in.  It will only stop the whole program if it is executed at the top level. To check if that's the problem, comment out your if statement and replace it with a simple "stop".   If THAT fails, then you know what the problem is, and you could create a global called "stop-flag?", replace the "stop" in your if test with " set stop-flag? true ", and at the start of your go step check "if stop-flag? true [stop].

Comment: Thank you very much, Wade Schuette. My model stopped now :))